# Access to specific cell value using name of a table

Tags: excel, vba

Suppose that we define 5X20 cells (for example E10:Y14) as CPL using name manager. Is there any way to get the value of 3rd row and 6th column in a cell? What about all the values of 6th columns? If we need to get access to the values of 6th column in VBA, what would be the solution? 
I know that I can name the 6th column separately and use that. But I am looking for a simpler way, since the table is large and I don't want to end up with huge number of names.

Best regards,

Comment: Do an `offset` from `CPL.range("A1")`?

Comment: in vba `Range("CPL").Cells(3,6)` would give you the cell in the 3rd row and 6th columns.  `Range("CPL").Column(6)` would give you the 6th column.

Comment: @findwindow CPL was named using the name manager not a range variable in vba.

Comment: @ScottCraner see what I said about embarrassing myself =P

Comment: Thanks both of you. Actually I used the following code inside a button:
{Sheet1.Cells(33, 8) = Range("CPL").Cells(3, 6)}
It dose not work. Any idea?

Comment: There are so many things that it could be.  Do this, in the immediate window put `? Range("CPL").Cells(3, 6)`  and see if it returns the correct value.

Comment: Sorry it is working. The only empty cell in my CPL table is cell (3,6)! 
By the way, the first thing that I tested was {=range("CPL").cells(3,1)} in a cell and I received a formula error.

Comment: There is difference between vba and formulas, what was given is not a formula and will not work pasting directly in a cell.  It will only work in vba.